# scilab - write multiple images to a folder

Tags: image-processing, compiler-errors, scilab

I am currently working in `scilab 5.5.2`. I need to write multiple images to a folder. I have installed `sivp` and `ipd` toolboxes.

But it shows error 115! as

> Warning !!! Scilab has found a critical error (Unknown exception)
>   with "sivp" function. Save your data and restart Scilab. end  !--error
>   115  Stack problem detected within a loop. A primitive function has
>   been called with a wrong number of output arguments. No output
>   argument test has been made for this function.

Can anybody help????

Comment: What commands do you use to "write multiple images"?

Comment: s1=string(jj);
outfile=strcat('C:\Users\dell\Desktop\example_sci\ritsclera\',s1);
imwrite(sclera,outfile);

Comment: What happens if you perform the most simple example of imwrite:
`im=rand(200,300);`
`ret = imwrite(im, 'rand.png');`

Comment: that doesnt make any differences.The values of 'im' not loaded to ret.

Comment: @diana Did you try to use another function like `xs2png` ?